# hitTest() usage in swift

Tags: swift, hittest

```
let subView = parentView.hitTest(point, with: nil)
```

> Return Value

The view object that is the farthest descendent of the current view and contains point. Returns nil if the point lies completely outside the receiver’s view hierarchy.

// As i implemented it detects view which contains the point. But in documentation what does farthest descendent mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say I have a `View3` inside a `View2` inside another `View1` (View1 - > View2 - > View3) and I tapped on `View3`, then it also means I tapped on `View2` and by that logic on `View1` as all of those are nested. now since the touch point lies on the `View3` thus, the `View3` (farthest in hierarchy of outmost view `View1`) gets returned.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a hierarchy of views, and call `hitTest` on a parent view, "farthest descendant" means that `hitTest` will return the specific descendant view containing the given point.